# mongoDb database form-data empty response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I am sending Rest `POST` Request(form-data) using postman to `mongoDb`. Even after providing all the key-value pairs in the Model, only the `product _id` gets stored into the database not other array of objects. Here's my model schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    price:  Number, 
    editor1: String, 
    year: String,
    quantity: Number,
    subject: String,
    newProduct:  String,
    relatedProduct: String,
    //coverImage: { type: String, required: false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

And here's my POST request for the products:

```
exports.products_create_product = (req, res, next) => {
  const product = new Product(req.body);
  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Created product successfully",
        createdProduct: {
          name: result.name,
          price: result.price,
          _id: result._id,
          request: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + result._id
          }
        }
    });
  })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

And this is my result output:

```
{
    "message": "Created product successfully",
    "createdProduct": {
        "_id": "5b2df3420e8b7d1150f6f7f6",
        "request": {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/products/5b2df3420e8b7d1150f6f7f6"
        }
    }
}
```

Tried every possible way to solve this but in vain.

Comment: are you calling the function in any route

Comment: @PrajvalM yes. All particular routes has been defined

Answer (score 0):

try the `callback`

```
 product.save((err,result) =>{

     if(err){
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
      return false
     }

      res.status(201).json({
            message: "Created product successfully",
            createdProduct: {
              name: result.name,
              price: result.price,
              _id: result._id,
              request: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/products/" + result._id
              }
            }
    })
```

Comment: and also check req.body  match to your collection field

Comment: all the collections are similar to the model fields

Comment: @PriyaJain change header in your post man form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

First let's try to understand why this happens ?  ,

When you use `.json()` method inside this method it uses [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function what this function does is that take any JavaScript value and convert it to **JSON string** for example

```js
let product = {
    name : 'p1' ,
    price : 200
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(product)); // {"name":"p1","price":200}
```

that's good , but you should know that if this function during the conversion see any undefined values it will be omitted ,
for example

```js
let product = {
    id:"23213214214214"
} // product doesn't have name property and its undefind  
console.log(JSON.stringify({
    id:product.id ,
    name : product.name
})); // {"id":"23213214214214"}
```

if you look at the example above you'll see that because the value of name is **undefined ** you get a JSON output but only with the id value , and any value that is undefined will not be in the result .

> that's the main reason why you get the result with only the product._id because other values like **price** and **name** are undefined  .

so what to do to solve this problem ?

- log the `req.body` and make sure that it has properties like name and price and I think this is the main reason of the problem because when you create the product variable it will only has the _id prop because other props are not exist .
- after you create the product log it to the console and make sure that it has other properties like name and price

Comment: I even tried that but still getting same result: only _id

Comment: Did you check the req.body ? can you share its output ?

Comment: @Piyu Do one thing, show your Schema and req.body's data.

Answer (score 0):

@mostafa yes I did tried.

```
{
"count": 3,
"products": [
    {
        "_id": "5b2e2d0cb70f5f0020e72cb6",
        "request": {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "https://aa-backend.herokuapp.com/products/5b2e2d0cb70f5f0020e72cb6"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b2e2d37b70f5f0020e72cb7",
        "request": {
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "https://aa-backend.herokuapp.com/products/5b2e2d37b70f5f0020e72cb7"
        }
    },
    {
```

this is the only output I am getting.